# Is a Lebesgue measurable subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ a Borel measurable set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Assume that $H$ is a Lebesgue measurable additive subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$. Is $H$ necessarily a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: If $H$ has positive measure, then $H-H=H$, thus 0 is interior point of $H$ (Steinhaus theorem) and $H=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thanks. Very interesting point.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No.  Let $\langle A \rangle$ be a proper Borel subgroup of ${\mathbb R}$ generated by an algebraically independent Borel set $A$ with the cardinality of the continuum (such a set was constructed in

*J. v. Neumann*, MR 1512442 [**Ein System algebraisch unabhängiger zahlen**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01459089), *Math. Ann.* **99** (1928), no. 1, 134--141.

, see also the discussion in

*Barthélemy Le Gac*, MR 687640 [**Some properties of Borel subgroups of real numbers**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2043358), *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* **87** (1983), no. 4, 677--680.

).  By the [Steinhaus lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus_theorem), $\langle A \rangle$ has measure zero, thus $\langle A' \rangle$ is a Lebesgue measurable subgroup for every $A' \subset A$.  But this gives $2^{\mathfrak c}$ such subgroups, more than the cardinality of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, so at least one of these subgroups must be non-Borel.

Comment: Is it obvious that the $\mathbb{Q}$-span of a Borel set, is a Borel set?

Comment: That's probably not true in general, but the construction of von Neumann is sigma-compact, and this will generate another sigma-compact set (as discussed in the paper of Le Gac).